# Refreshing dynamic listviews in JQM when navigating between pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm creating a mobile app using jquery mobile and cordova. I've successfully loaded a dynamic listview from a json ajax call. My issue is that when I navigate to another page, then press the back button, the original page's listview does not load and there is nothing where it should be. If I refresh the page, the listview appears. Rather than refresh the whole page every time I navigate to this page, how would I refresh just the listview?

I've tried refreshing the listview both when the DOM and the window have loaded, and before both, and using $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pagenamehere", function() {}); to no avail.

To be more specific, I have two pages with listviews. The navigational steps go as follows:
1. load page 1: listview shows
2. navigate to page 2: its listview does not show
3. press back: page 1 listview shows
4. navigate to page 2: its listview still does not show
5. refresh page 2: its listview DOES show
6. press back: page 1's listview does NOT show

This process should make it clear that the listview only loads when the url is directly input or reloaded; for some reason navigation between pages (different html files) breaks this.

Comment: Is this being caused by the cached page loading and not executing the refresh code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have script inside the head tag of the second page and this page is loaded through Ajax, then the script won't execute.

Try to move your script from the head tag inside the second page's div (`<div data-role="page" id="mySecondPage">`) or create a JS file and load it on the first page's load. Relevant example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247516/map-view-is-not-loading-with-phonegap/12252010#12252010)

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to perform pages transitions so during the transition jQuery Mobile will only inject the contents of the response's body element (or more specifically the data-role="page" element). Nothing in the head of the page will be used (except the page title).

In conclusion, any scripts and styles referenced in the head of a page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax. They will execute if the page is requested via HTTP and that's why your listview is loaded after a full page refresh.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help and the useful info about JQM!